# JavaMail - Sending multiple emails in a loop

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have been tasked with writing an application that will send an email to 1-3 recipients, with 5 possible Survey questions. The questions and recipients are pulled from a Properties file, and the number of emails to send are also held in this file.

My issue is, I cannot get the emails to send with this current code, any suggestions?

**EmailSend**

```
for(int j=0; j<noOfEmails; j++)
            {
                if(noOfEmails==1)
                {
                    for(int i=0; i<noOfQuest; i++)
                    {
                        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient1));
                        if(noOfQuest==1)
                        {
                            message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                                "Response 1: " + answers[0]);
                        }
                        if(noOfQuest==2)
                        {
                            message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName +
                                                "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 2: " + answers[1]);
                        }
                        if(noOfQuest==3)
                        {
                            message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName +
                                                "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 3: " + answers[2]);
                        }
                        if(noOfQuest==4)
                        {
                            message.setText("Username: " + fName + sName +
                                                "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 4: " + answers[3]);
                        }
                        if(noOfQuest==5)
                        {
                            message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName +
                                                "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 4: " + answers[3] + "\n" +
                                                                "Response 4: " + answers[4]);
                        }

                        Transport.send(message);
                    }
                    if(noOfEmails==2)
                    {
                        for(int i=0; i<noOfQuest; i++)
                        {
                            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient2));
                            if(noOfQuest==1)
                            {
                                message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 1: " + answers[0]);
                            }
                            if(noOfQuest==2)
                            {
                                message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName +
                                                    "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 2: " + answers[1]);
                            }
                            if(noOfQuest==3)
                            {
                                message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName +
                                                    "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 3: " + answers[2]);
                            }
                            if(noOfQuest==4)
                            {
                                message.setText("Username: " + fName + sName +
                                                    "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                                "Response 4: " + answers[3]);
                            }
                            if(noOfQuest==5)
                            {
                                message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName +
                                                    "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                                "Response 4: " + answers[3] + "\n" +
                                                                    "Response 4: " + answers[4]);
                            }

                            Transport.send(message);
                        }
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==3)
                    {
                        for(int i=0; i<noOfQuest; i++)
                        {
                            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient3));
                            if(noOfQuest==1)
                            {
                                message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 1: " + answers[0]);
                            }
                            if(noOfQuest==2)
                            {
                                message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName +
                                                    "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 2: " + answers[1]);
                            }
                            if(noOfQuest==3)
                            {
                                message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName +
                                                    "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 3: " + answers[2]);
                            }
                            if(noOfQuest==4)
                            {
                                message.setText("Username: " + fName + sName +
                                                    "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                                "Response 4: " + answers[3]);
                            }
                            if(noOfQuest==5)
                            {
                                message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName +
                                                    "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                                "Response 4: " + answers[3] + "\n" +
                                                                    "Response 4: " + answers[4]);
                            }
                            Transport.send(message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I would recommend reading up on loops, in the online Java tutorials.  Everything you need to know is right there.

Comment: Will-do thanks, I'll post my answer when I get it working.

Comment: Ignoring all the basic coding inefficiencies in there, you'll need to explain in more detail what you mean by "cannot get the emails to send".  Start with this [JavaMail FAQ entry on debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: @BillShannon My issue was that the line 'Transport.send(message)' wasn't in the correct area of the loop, and the loop wasn't correctly structured. Please see my answer for a working version.

With regards to your mention of inefficiency, you make a valid point but for this project, it isn't a requirement. Keep up the good commenting though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little experimentation, I noticed that 2 of the 3 if statements were nested in the first, causing a fallthrough.

Here is the working code:

**for loop to check a configuration file, using a read **

```
for(int i=0; i<noOfEmails; i++)
        {
            if(noOfEmails==1)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<noOfQuest; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println("In Loop[" + j + "] : recipient1: "+ recipient1);


                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient1));                            
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==1)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0]);                           
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==2)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1]);                           
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==3)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 3: " + answers[2]);                           
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==4)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 4: " + answers[3]);                           
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==5)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 4: " + answers[3] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 4: " + answers[4]);
                    }
                }
            }   

            if(noOfEmails==2)
            {
                for(int k=0; k<noOfQuest; k++)
                {
                    System.out.println("In Loop[" + k + "] : recipient2: "+ recipient2);

                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient1));
                    }
                    if(i==1)
                    {
                        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient2));
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==1)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0]);                               
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==2)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1]);                               
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==3)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 3: " + answers[2]);                               
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==4)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 4: " + answers[3]);                               
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==5)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 4: " + answers[3] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 4: " + answers[4]);                               
                    }
                }
            }

            if(noOfEmails==3)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient1));
                    System.out.println(recipient1);
                }
                if(i==1)
                {
                    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient2));
                    System.out.println(recipient2);
                }
                if(i==2)
                {
                    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient3));
                    System.out.println(recipient3);
                }

                for(int l=0; l<noOfQuest; l++)
                {
                    System.out.println("In Loop[" + l + "] : recipient3: "+ recipient3);


                    if(noOfQuest==1)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0]);                               
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==2)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1]);                               
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==3)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 3: " + answers[2]);                               
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==4)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 4: " + answers[3]);                               
                    }
                    if(noOfQuest==5)
                    {
                        message.setText("Username: " + fName + " "+ sName + "\n" +
                                            "Response 1: " + answers[0] + "\n" +
                                                "Response 2: " + answers[1] + "\n" +
                                                    "Response 3: " + answers[2] + "\n" +
                                                        "Response 4: " + answers[3] + "\n" +
                                                            "Response 4: " + answers[4]);
                    }
                }
            }
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent: " + message);
        }
```

For anyone that is confused, "noOfEmails | noOfQuest" are 2 variables that are read from a properties file.